# Sudden Word vba error '-2146959355 (800800005)' No Such interface Supported

Tags: vba, pdf, text, adobe

Based on this previous question:

[Extracting whole Sentences from PDFs (as best as possible) - Plain Text From PDF without inserting line breaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73628493/extracting-whole-sentences-from-pdfs-as-best-as-possible-plain-text-from-pdf)

Trying to achieve a similar script to convert PDFs to accessible text documents i.e. skip out the word conversion.

Previously I used the following code which worked fine:

```
Sub LoopThroughFiles()
    
    Dim StrFile As String
    Dim pdfPath As String
    
    StrFile = Dir("C:\temp\PDFs\")
    fileRoot = "C:\temp\PDFs\"
    If Right(fileRoot, 1) <> "\" Then fileRoot = fileRoot & "\" 'ensure terminating \
    
    Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
        
        Debug.Print StrFile
        n = StrFile
        pdfPath = fileRoot & StrFile
        
        Debug.Print pdfPath
        
    'Convert to WordDoc
    success = ConvertPdf2(pdfPath, fileRoot & StrFile & ".doc")
    StrFile = Dir
    On Error Resume Next
        
    oWd.Quit
        
    'Convert to PlainText
    Debug.Print pdfPath & ".doc"

    success2 = GetTextFromWord(pdfPath & ".doc", n)
    
Loop
End Sub

'returns true if conversion was successful (based on whether `Open` succeeded or not)
Function ConvertPdf2(pdfPath As String, textPath As String) As Boolean
    Dim AcroXApp As Acrobat.AcroApp
    Dim AcroXAVDoc As Acrobat.AcroAVDoc
    Dim AcroXPDDoc As Acrobat.AcroPDDoc
    Dim jsObj As Object, success As Boolean

    Set AcroXApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")
    Set AcroXAVDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.AVDoc")
    success = AcroXAVDoc.Open(pdfPath, "Acrobat") '<<< returns false if fails
    If success Then
    
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:2")) 'Helps PC have some time to go through data, can cause PC to freeze without

        Set AcroXPDDoc = AcroXAVDoc.GetPDDoc
        Set jsObj = AcroXPDDoc.GetJSObject
        jsObj.SaveAs textPath, "com.adobe.acrobat.doc"
        AcroXAVDoc.Close False
    End If
    AcroXApp.Hide
    AcroXApp.Exit
    ConvertPdf2 = success 'report success/failure
End Function

Function GetTextFromWord(DocStr As String, n)

    Dim filePath As String
    Dim fso As FileSystemObject
    Dim fileStream As TextStream
    Dim oWd As Object, oDoc As Object, fileRoot As String
    Const wdFormatText As Long = 2, wdCRLF As Long = 0
    
    Set fso = New FileSystemObject
    Set oWd = CreateObject("word.application")
    
    fileRoot = "C:\temp\PDFs" 'read this once
    If Right(fileRoot, 1) <> "\" Then fileRoot = fileRoot & "\" 'ensure terminating \
    
            Set oDoc = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next 'ignore error if no document...
            Set oDoc = oWd.Documents.Open(DocStr)
            On Error GoTo 0      'stop ignoring errors
            
            Debug.Print n
            If Not oDoc Is Nothing Then
                filePath = fileRoot & n & ".txt"  'filename
                Debug.Print filePath
                
                
        oDoc.SaveAs2 Filename:=filePath, _
        FileFormat:=wdFormatText, LockComments:=False, Password:="", _
        AddToRecentFiles:=False, WritePassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, _
        EmbedTrueTypeFonts:=False, SaveNativePictureFormat:=False, SaveFormsData _
        :=False, SaveAsAOCELetter:=False, Encoding:=65001, InsertLineBreaks:=False _
        , AllowSubstitutions:=True, LineEnding:=wdCRLF, CompatibilityMode:=0
        
    oDoc.Close False
    
    End If
    oWd.Quit
                
   
    GetTextFromWord = success2
    
End Function
```

Now I just want to use Adobe to generate accessible text files fom PDFs but get the error:

[image]

Unsure if this is something that has changed from my company's side or something I can try to fix.

Answer (score 0):

A nonideal solution to open via shell, and then send keys. Work in real-time so takes ages and cant use the computer whilst waiting.

```
Sub ConvertPDFToTextWithAdobeAcrobat()
    Dim InputFolderPath As String
    Dim OutputFolderPath As String
    Dim PDFFileName As String
    Dim PDFFilePath As String
    Dim TextFilePath As String
    Dim AcroApp As Object
    Dim PDFDoc As Object
    
    ' Ask the user to select the input folder
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .Title = "Select Folder with PDF Files"
        If .Show = -1 Then
            InputFolderPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With
    
    ' Ask the user to select the output folder- Reckitt\Desktop\ICH Q3D\ICH Q3D\PDF\PDFOCR\TEST\LGC314252-001_Gaviscon Peppermint Liquid_8119148_CofA v2*.txt
    
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .Title = "Select Output Folder for Text Files"
        If .Show = -1 Then
            OutputFolderPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With
    
    ' Loop through all PDF files in the input folder
    PDFFileName = Dir(InputFolderPath & "*.pdf")
    Do While PDFFileName <> ""
        ' Set the PDF file path
        PDFFilePath = InputFolderPath & PDFFileName
        
        ' Open the PDF file with Adobe Acrobat XI Standard using Shell
        Shell "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat 11.0\Acrobat\Acrobat.exe """ & PDFFilePath & """", vbNormalFocus
        
        ' Pause briefly to allow Acrobat to open the file
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:02") ' Wait for 2 seconds
        
        ' Generate the text file path in the output folder
        TextFilePath = (PDFFileName)
```